How do I download my image converted to pdf using expo-media-library
I am unable to create the asset using createAssetAsync method from the expo-media-library package
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";
import * as MediaLibraray from "expo-media-library";
import { PDFDocument } from "pdf-lib";
import { Buffer } from "buffer";

export const generatePdf = async (imageUri, 

 dimensions) => {
  global.Buffer = Buffer;
  try {
    //creation of PDF
    const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.create();

    //Load image to the PDF
    const imageBytes = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(imageUri, {
      encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
    });

    //Embedding the image
    const embeddedImage =
      photoType === "jpg" || "jpeg"
        ? await pdfDoc.embedJpg(imageBytes)
        : await pdfDoc.embedPng(imageBytes);

    //create a page with specific dimensions
    const page = pdfDoc.addPage([dimensions.width, dimensions.height]);

    //Scaling factor
    const scaleFactor = Math.min(
      dimensions.width / embeddedImage.width,
      dimensions.height / embeddedImage.height
    );

    //Scale the image and draw the image on the page
    const { width, height } = embeddedImage.scale(scaleFactor);
    page.drawImage(embeddedImage, {
      x: (page.getWidth() - width) / 2,
      y: page.getHeight() - height / 2,
      width,
      height,
    });

    //Seralize the bytes
    const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();

    //convert raw binary to Base64
    const pdfBase64 = Buffer.from(pdfBytes).toString("base64");

    //Get a path for the generated PDF file
    const fileUri = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}generated_image.pdf`;

    //save the file to the disk
    await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(fileUri, pdfBase64, {
      encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
    });
    return fileUri;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error generating the PDF : ", error.message);
    throw new Error("Failed to generate PDF !");
  }
};

//Function to move the PDf to dowqnloads folder (on Device )

export const movePdfToDownloads = async (pdfPath) => {
  try {
    const fileInfo = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(pdfPath);
    // console.log(`file Info : ${fileInfo}`);
    // console.log(`PDF path : ${pdfPath}`);
    if (!fileInfo.exists) {
      throw new Error("the specified file does not exist.", pdfPath);
    }
    // Media Library Starts ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    const downloadFolder = FileSystem.documentDirectory + "Download/";
    const fileName = "generated.pdf";
    const downloadPath = `${downloadFolder}${fileName}`;

    await FileSystem.copyAsync({
      from: pdfPath,
      to: downloadPath,
    });

    const asset = await MediaLibraray.createAssetAsync(downloadPath);
    console.log("Asset Created", asset);
    const album = await MediaLibraray.getAlbumAsync("Download");
    console.log(`Album : ${album}`);
    if (!album) {
      await MediaLibraray.createAlbumAsync("Download", asset);
    } else {
      await MediaLibraray.addAssetsToAlbumAsync([asset], album, false);
    }

    console.log(
      `PDF successfully moveed to Download folder at : ${downloadPath}`
    );

    return downloadPath;
    /* 
    Media Library Ends ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error moving the File to download folder :", error.message);
    throw new Error(`Failed to move the PDF to downloads : ${error.message}`);
  }
};

So, whenever I execute my code I land up getting the following error:

Error moving the File to download folder : Could not create asset.

What should I update in the code to save the PDF created on my device?

Hello, and welcome ! I'd suggest you completely use FileSystem for saving a PDF instead of MediaLibrary (you made a typo tho). MediaLibrary is primarily intended for photos and videos. You may achieve what you want using writeAsStringAsync() which allows you to save your file using base64 as well. You might also need requestDirectoryPermissionsAsync()
